# Ext.grid.ColumnModel sorting does not work

Tags: extjs

I have few columns in my grid. The column set for default sorting works fine. But sorting does not work for other columns. I have sortable :true for these columns. Following is the sample code. Please help

```
 var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    root: 'services',
    totalProperty: 'totalCount',
    idProperty: 'serviceKey',
    remoteSort: true,

    fields: [             
        {name: 'type'},
        {name: 'state'}, 
        {name: 'name'}           
    ],

    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ext/ServiceListServlet?encodedFilter=<%=com.digev.fw.xml.Base64.encodeAsBase64String(FilterFactory.serializeFiltersToString(filterList).getBytes())%>', timeout: 900000
    }),
    autoLoad: false
});


   var cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([{
       header: "<b>Type</b>",
       dataIndex: 'type',
       fixed: true,
       width: 40
    },{
       header: "<b>State</b>",
       dataIndex: 'state',
       width: 40,
       fixed: true,
       sortable: true
    },{
        id: 'name',
        header: "<b>Name</b>",
        dataIndex: 'name',
        renderer: nameAnchor,
        hideable : false,
        width: 250,
        sortable: true
    }
]);

  store.setDefaultSort('name', 'asc');
```

Answer (score 0):

What is going on when you click to each of columns headers? Request send? 
May be server is returning not sorted data for one of this parameters? Sorry 4 my engish)